# Devise(STI) create another user account type using his previous credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid, devise-invitable

I am using devise with Single Table inheritance in Rails4 ans Mongoid

```
Class User
  #devise class
  validates :email, :uniqueness => { :scope => :_type }
end

class Patient < User
end

class Doctor < User
end

class Hospital < User
end
```

If i create an account as Doctor the type will be `_type: "Doctor"` then if he wants to create an account as Patient or Hospital then first check into the database if email already exists with any of account type then just using that email create an account with previous credentials.

So i don't want to give all data while registering for creating other account type.

How to achieve this scenario!!! Please help me......

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I don't use inheritance. I do something like this:

```
Class User
  field :name
  field :email
end

Class Patient
  has_one :user

  attr_accesor :email
  field: disease

  before_create do
    existing_user = User.where( email: email ).first

    if uxisting_user
      user = uxisting_user
    else
      # you need create first an user
    end
  end

  def name
    user.name
  end
end
```

Now if user exist already, only need email field for search it and you can get all this informabotion:

```
User.create( name: 'User1', email: 'user1@email.com' )
Patient.create( email: 'user1@email.com', disease: 'headache' )
Patient.first.name
=> "User1"
```

Also, if you change user information it is changed in Patient and the same for others classes.